# When using random.uniform(a,b), is b inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: python

I was exploring the random module and can't find a correct answer to whether b is inclusive or exclusive in `random.uniform(a, b)`.

In a code like `random.uniform(0, 1)`, some answers say 1 is included while others say 1 is never produced. What's the correct answer?

Comment: `help(random.uniform)`: _Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding._

Comment: Can you show such an answer that says 1 is included in that example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`random.uniform(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) suggests that you may encounter cases where the upper limit `b` is included in the range due to how floating-point numbers are represented, but it's not guaranteed:

> Return a random floating point number N such that `a <= N <= b` for `a <= b` and `b <= N <= a` for `b < a`.
>
> The end-point value `b` may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation `a + (b-a) * random()`.

So sometimes the upper limit `b` may be included, and sometimes it may not be.

Comment: In particular, their `random.uniform(0, 1)` never produces 1, and `random.uniform(1, 1)` always does.

Comment: @KellyBundy - Interestingly, if we take the formula `a + (b-a) * random()`, then `random.uniform(0, 1)` is `0 + (1-0) * random()` or `1 * random()` and since `random()` is always < 1.0, `random.uniform(0,1)` would never be 1.0.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, that's why.

Comment: @tdelaney Granted, it's not *guaranteed* that the function uses that expression, but the doc suggests it and CPython *has* used it ever since it introduced the function 23 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

> Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.
>
> The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random().

If you have a question about how a function works, it's always best to start by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The `a + (b-a) * random()` from the documentation is also the actual implementation (at least in CPython, and I highly doubt that other impressions would deviate from that, especially since it's stated in the doc).

And `random()` is implemented as:

```
(int.from_bytes(_urandom(7)) >> 3) * 2**-53
```

So for given `a` and `b`, you can determine whether `b` is inclusive:

```
def inclusive(a, b):
    max_random = (int.from_bytes(bytes([255] * 7)) >> 3) * 2**-53
    max_uniform = a + (b-a) * max_random
    return max_uniform == b
```

Examples ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY9NDoIwEIX3nGJ2tggmQIjGpFzEGNJKqyTSklKMhHASN2z0Tq69iEXwbxYvk8mbl_ddbmVjDkr2_bU2wl_dHxkXkMvdsa7yE0fUA4bXDtgp6DnVVGaqAAIol2YhtCpS1hheoVE3YRxvwYUlxpAkEGG7h67rx9EnoZa5UHqIoDAHxHw6mL7ZL6Pmptby30-AOQ61f4FjD8BsSbAve44CD4JgKllqWwyJWUtJBy0b5BeGYdLN8Ig6Eb_Jnw)):

```
a=1 b=1 inclusive(a,b)=True
a=1 b=2 inclusive(a,b)=True
a=1 b=3 inclusive(a,b)=True
a=1 b=4 inclusive(a,b)=False
a=1 b=5 inclusive(a,b)=True
a=1 b=6 inclusive(a,b)=False
a=1 b=7 inclusive(a,b)=False
a=1 b=8 inclusive(a,b)=False
a=1 b=9 inclusive(a,b)=True
a=1 b=10 inclusive(a,b)=False
```